# How can Heartbleed checkers determine if a site is vulnerable?

Tags: tls, openssl, heartbleed

As far as I know, there is not a way to obtain OpenSSL's version from a website. Then what kind of information does a Heartbleed checker obtain so it can determine if a site is safe from Heartbleed or not?

Comment: @begueradj: I'm not sure this is a duplicate (related yes, but not duplicate). I have the impression that the OP already knows about Hearbleed vulnerability checkers, the question seems merely here to understand **how** do this checkers work since the OpenSSL version is not available remotely (no version banner for instance).

Comment: yes that's what i asked for .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Heartbleed bug involves asking the server to return a block of memory that is larger than the actual information being returned. A vulnerable server will return whatever is in memory beyond the data structure it's returning. So, if you ask a server to return the extra memory and it does, then the server is vulnerable.

You can examine the [code diffs for the patch here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/731f431497f463f3a2a97236fe0187b11c44aead). There's a lot of duplication in the code but the basic change is to add this:

```
if (1 + 2 + payload + 16 > s->s3->rrec.length)
    return 0; /* silently discard */
```

So you can see how it now fails if you request a buffer larger than the actual size.

Comment: @Echidna - if you are happy with the answer, you can choose it as the correct one by clicking the checkmark next to the question - https://security.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers